# Sending and receiving data using javascript http

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am sending data in json format from javascript using XMLHttpRequest and receiving data at node.js file as following

**client.js**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(Idata),
    url: AjaxURL,
    success: function (result) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');

console.log("server initialized");

var server = http.createServer(function (req, response) {
    req.on('data', function (data) {

        var d = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("data : " + d.OperationType);

    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        response.end();
    });

}).listen(3000);
```

Now i successfully got the value of operationtype but the at client browser this error is showing:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: the Idata which i am sending from client is as below :                                       var Idata = { 'OperationType': 'GID', 'DNS': '' + objName + '', 'fn': 'SetGUID' };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary problem is that you are making a `"GET"` request. A data payload/HTTP request body cannot be uploaded with an XMLHttpRequest `"GET"` request. See the [specification of XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20080415/): "If stored method is GET act as if the data argument is null."

In order to send data, you should make a `"POST"` request, in this case:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", AjaxURL, true);
```

In response to updated question:

For security reasons, your AJAX request will not be allowed to access your server hosted at `localhost:3000` unless the AJAX request is initiated from a page served by `localhost:3000` OR you tell your server to allow "cross-origin" requests. The latter can be accomplished by adding a line like this to your server:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

This sets a header that tells the browser to allow AJAX requests to `localhost:3000` even if the request is initiated from a page that was not served by `localhost:3000`.

Comment: Thanks. post works well but the error is now showing at client browser which i mentioned in my updated question

Comment: I updated my answer. If you have any further questions, you should create a new question instead of modifying this one. Significantly modifying your previous question makes it difficult for others to follow the discussion and benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks David, now it is working well. This answer made my work much easier, thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

1. In `client.js`, output the value `Idata`(using `console.log`) right before sending it.
2. Use the 'Network' tab in Chrome(or equivalent in your favorite browser) to check what is actually being sent.
3. In `server.js`, output the value `data`(using `console.log`) right after recieving it.

That will probably give you a clue as to where it went wrong, which will help you determine your next course of action. If you still don't know how to proceed, update the question and I will update my answer.

What I can say right now based on my (very lacking) knowledge of node.js, is that if the variable `data` is being treated as an object, `store += data;` is not a good idea, as that would mean you are trying to add an object to an (empty) string.
(Probably resulting in the object returning "[object Object]", or some such)

Comment: Idata is having value [object object] at both client and server side